# What steam wand to replace my Gaggia Carezza old machine?

Tags: steamed-milk, coffee-machines

I have an old model of Gaggie Carezza that can be found [here](http://www.gaggia-parts.co.uk/Gaggia-Coffee-Machines/Manual/Gaggia-Carezza). The steam wand needs to be replaced. Does anyone know which one is suitable? I have been looking at this [Rancilio Silvia steam wand](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Modified-Rancilio-Silvia-Gaggia-ESPRESS/dp/B00MZA8OVU/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1446659008&sr=8-3&keywords=rancilio%20silvia) but not very sure if it would fit before making my order.

Many thanks,